# store data ordered by a row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I somehow make that mysql inserts data in a way that the database keeps an predefined order?

Let's say I make a highscore list. I could always use ORDER BY when selecting the stuff, but all the ordering in 1,000,000+ datasets takes alot of performance when a user browses the highscore list.

My idea is now that I want to insert the data in a way, that the table is always ordered by score desc, so all the ORDER BY work doesn't have to happen when users browse the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also there is another solution. If you store these much records in order by than there is tedious. Another way is you can create index on high score column so mysql internally create one index so when you try to fetch these record in order by than its performance is better than direct fetching query.

Please create index of high score column.

Comment: I already have an index on that column, but it's still very slow when sorting. So I thought about a second table which is generated like once per night and it is preordered, so selecting stuff will not require an order by anymore.

Comment: If you have a (proper) index, using `order by` should not be significantly slower. Did you compare the identical queries with and without the order by? If in doubt, you can create an [Execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) for both queries to see where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 2):

Tables have no inherent order that you should *rely* upon (they may, by coincidence, return rows in the same order that they were inserted, or by primary key sort order), so if you need a particular order, you should always use an `ORDER BY` clause.

However, the system may be able to perform the ordering more cheaply if it has an index available on the column on which you will have your `ORDER BY` clause - so add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table_Scores ON `Table` (score desc);
```